# How to reload a function in Python?

Tags: python, function

I want to insert two different paths with the same name of python file. Is it possible to reload goal_func without reestarting the kernel?

step 1:

```
path = 'a*/goal.py'
ruta_carpeta = path[:-8]
sys.path.insert(1, ruta_carpeta)
from goal import goal_func
```

step 2:

```
path = 'b*/goal.py'
ruta_carpeta = path[:-8]
sys.path.insert(1, ruta_carpeta)
from goal import goal_func
```

goal_func has not been updated.

Comment: have you tried `importlib.reload` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but it tells me that it is not a module.

Comment: Reloading modules is not recommended except for playing in the Python console. What is your more general objective here?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) on the module, then reimport the function:

```py
import importlib
import goal
importlib.reload(goal) # reload the module
# now import the function
from goal import goal_func
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a reload function in the 'imp' module. Using this we can reload the imported ones.

```
import imp
imp.reload(function/module)
```